# Indian health related data sets from research point of view

Tags: medical

i want to carry out some analytics in health care field but i am unable to get Indian data set.Does anyone know from where to get the same dataset ?can anyone please help?

Comment: dhs and ipumsi both have indian data..  see http://asdfree.com/